# Why is my GUI unresponsive while a SwingWorker thread runs?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swingworker

I have a SwingWorker thread with an IOBound task which is totally locking up the interface while it runs. Swapping out the normal workload for a counter loop has the same result. The SwingWorker looks basically like this:

```
public class BackupWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

private static String uname = null;
private static String pass = null;
private static String filename = null;
static String status = null;

BackupWorker (String uname, String pass, String filename) {
    this.uname = uname;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.filename = filename;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            BackupObject bak = newBackupObject(uname,pass,filename);
    return "Done!";
}
```

}

The code that kicks it off lives in a class that extends JFrame:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String cmd = event.getActionCommand();

    if (BACKUP.equals(cmd)) { 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                final StatusFrame statusFrame = new StatusFrame();
                statusFrame.setVisible(true);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run () {
                        statusFrame.beginBackup(uname,pass,filename);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the interesting part of StatusFrame:

```
public void beginBackup(final String uname, final String pass, final String filename) {
    worker = new BackupWorker(uname, pass, filename);
    worker.execute();

    try {
        System.out.println(worker.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

So far as I can see, everything "long-running" is handled by the worker, and everything that touches the GUI on the EDT. Have I tangled things up somewhere, or am I expecting too much of SwingWorker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the call to `SwingWorker.get()` in your `beginBackup` method. Take a look at the [docs for this method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get%28%29):

> Waits if necessary for the computation
>   to complete, and then retrieves its
>   result.

This is a blocking call, hence your GUI becomes unresponsive.

(Also, is there any particular reason why you're doing an `invokeLater` from within an `invokeLater` call? You're already running on the EDT.)

Comment: What threw me off here was preceding the `get()` with a `while (!worker.isDone())` and seeing the same unresponsiveness.

I was seeing the GUI lock up before the `StatusFrame` finished drawing until I tried the ugly `Runnable` nesting. That issue is moot now.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for a working example. You will see that the get(...) method is invoked from within the process(...) method that is overridden in the SwingWorker class.